# fb:login-button doesn't show in angular/ionic app

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, ionic-framework

Hi I am trying to display the FB login button (js Facebook sdk) in my app, but the button doesn't show.

If you look at the markup below, you'll see that the login.html is a 'ionic modal', there's no 'ionic-view'.

Can you help figure out how to and where to code the displaying of the button ?

app.js:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'sAuth',  "isPhoneGap","connectionStatus", 'updateProDB', "$ionicPlatform", '$q', 'sessionService', 'imagesService', function($rootScope, $window, sAuth, isPhoneGap, connectionStatus, updateProDB, $ionicPlatform, $q, sessionService, imagesService) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  //CHECK IF PhoneGap and if online using the services.
  // console.log("avant connectionStatus, isPhoneGap = "+isPhoneGap);
  // console.log("ok connectionStatus = "+connectionStatus);

  //DEBUG
  //updateProDB(connectionStatus, debugOptionUseLocalDB);
  var promise = updateProDB.get();
  //console.log('promise dans app.js');
  //console.log(promise);
  promise.then(
          function(prodata) {
              var prodata = sessionService.get('prodata');

              var imagesUrls = imagesService.manage(prodata);
              console.log('imagesUrls in app.js :');
              console.log(imagesUrls);
              sessionService.store('imagesUrls', imagesUrls);
          },
          function(error) {

          });


  // FOR FACEBOOK LOGIN:

  $rootScope.user = {};

  $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // Executed when the SDK is loaded
    console.log("fbAsyncInit is launching FB.init...");
    FB.init({ 
      //  The app id of the web app; To register a new app visit Facebook App Dashboard ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ )
      appId: '583996261696416', 
      // Adding a Channel File improves the performance  of the javascript SDK, by addressing issues  with cross-domain communication in certain browsers.
      channelUrl: 'templates/channel.html', 
      //  Set if you want to check the authentication status at the start up of the app 
      status: true, 
      //        Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session  
      cookie: true,
      // Parse XFBML
      xfbml: true 
    });

    //sAuth.logout();
    sAuth.watchLoginChange();
    sAuth.getLoginStatus();


  };

  (function(d){
    // load the Facebook javascript SDK
    var js, 
    id = 'facebook-jssdk', 
    ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script'); 
    js.id = id; 
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

}])
```

login.html:

```
<div class="modal">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeLogin()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
   <fb:login-button show-faces="true" max-rows="1" size="large">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button> 
  </ion-content>
</div>
```

service.js:

```
.service('sAuth', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    this.watchLoginChange = function() {
        var _self = this;
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(res) {
        if (res.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('connected');
          /* The user is already logged,  is possible retrieve his personal info    */
          _self.getUserInfo();
          /* This is also the point where you should create a 
           session for the current user.
           For this purpose you can use the data inside the 
           res.authResponse object.
          */
        } 
        else {
            console.log("the user is not logged");
          /*   The user is not logged to the app, or into Facebook:  destroy the session on the server.   */
        }
        });
    };

    this.getLoginStatus = function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            console.log('connected selon getLoginStatus ');
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app

          } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            console.log('not connected selon getLoginStatus ');
          }
        });
    };

    this.getUserInfo = function() {
      var _self = this;
      FB.api('/me', function(res) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { 
          $rootScope.user = _self.user = res; 
        });
      });
    };

    this.logout = function() {
      var _self = this;
      FB.logout(function(response) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() { 
          $rootScope.user = _self.user = {}; 
        }); 
      });
    }

    return this;
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you just need to parse the button after it has been added to the DOM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

Also, make sure you try your code on a real server or localhost, not by just opening the html file in a browser.

Comment: Hi @luschn can you please tell me exactly where to put this and how to do it clean in my angular files ?

Comment: Shloud I use the ng-facebook https://ninjatronic.github.io/ngFacebook/ directive ? (I am new to angular)